# how can you make your bot send the second argument

Tags: javascript, discord.js

like !L JohnGameRage#0000 has gaven the L to user#0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to structure arguments is like this:

```
let full = message.content.substr(1).trim(); //remove the prefix
let split = full.split(/ +/g); //seperate the words in the String and put them into an array
let cmd = split[0]; //the command is the first word in the array
let args = split.slice(1); //the arguments are all words except for the first one
```

In your example `L` would be the command and `JohnGameRage#0000` would be the first argument.

You can read individual arguments from the array like this:

```js
//Command = !L firstArg secondArg thirdArg fourthArg etc
cmd //returns 'L'
args[0] //returns 'firstArg'
args[1] //returns 'secondArg '
args[2] //returns 'thirdArg '
args[3] //returns 'fourthArg '
args[4] //returns 'etc'
```